# div content table cell settings

Tags: html, css

Please find below fiddle what i tried

http://jsfiddle.net/9LdEc/

**code:**

html:

```
<div id="CorpDealerSearch">
     <div class="row">  
            <div class="left">
                 Quarter To Date
            </div>
            <div class="left">
              <a href="self">914</a>
            </div>
            <div class="left">
                 <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAEYAAAAZCAYAAACM9limAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAACoSURBVFhH7dkhDoMwFIfxJ5EcieNwG5IZJJY7IDhCBTeYm0JCgviTEJaxAUnfbL8mdVVffn0VNTMT+7KBifVdYIdCmF8YhLm5KoQhjG+KIgYxiPEVQIyvFzMGMdI4ztuOWUmJaZpBef5QllUqilZl2SmE12WnpMK8C0zTor5/qq4DYWKuz/FMkmJiIhGGVynGyecMYhCDGF8BxPh6MWMQ86cY/pXO/0or0qcGh0OW3F8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=">
            </div>
            <div class="left">
                <span>OFF TIER2</span>
            </div>
         </div>
        </div>
```

css:

```
#CorpDealerSearch{
    display:table;
    padding : 5px;
   border: 2px solid gray;
   border-radius:3px;
}
.row{
        display:table-row;
}

.left {
    display:table-cell;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:5px;
}
```

But I want the design like the screenshot below. How can I modify the fiddle to get the design like this?

I need to do changes only for the last cell.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/9LdEc/4/

I have added some of classes to your html and used the following css:

```
body {
    font-family: Arial;
}

#CorpDealerSearch {
    display:table;
    padding : 5px;
    border: 2px solid gray;
    border-radius:5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 25px;
}
#CorpDealerSearch a,
#CorpDealerSearch a:hover,
#CorpDealerSearch a:visited {
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.row {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.left {
    display:table-cell;
    display:inline-block;
    padding-left:5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
.tier {
    border-left: 2px dotted black;
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: but i need offtier background color to be applied full size of table. please refer the screenshot which was updated by me

Comment: add padding: 0px; to #CorpDealerSearch{} obviously.

Comment: @SivaRajini Updated my answer with a new fiddle